# Is this question off-topic? What should it be flagged as?

Tags: discussion, scope

I think this question is off-topic, but I am not sure:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372842/python-count-sides-of-square-building

It has two answers, but it looks like a homework problem. It could be too broad, and there also isn't a specific problem (like an error or something).

Thanks to the user who kindly suggested the duplicate in the comments, that solves my problem! :D

What should I flag it as?

Comment: @gnat thank you! this solves my problem. unfortunately, i accidentally clicked out of the "mark my question as solved by duplicate" window, so I have cast a flag to close this as a duplicate as well.

Answer (score -9):

Considering SO is for all things programming, I wouldn't say it's off topic.
Broad maybe but not off-topic.

Comment: well its not really for all things programming at all. the help center clearly specifies some guidelines.